# Matrix Summing with MATCH/INDEX

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a matrix with codes on the y-axis and a number of items in the x-axis. Each item can have multiple codes, which is shown by a 1 in the cell and a blank otherwise. I also have a list of prices for each item and want to find the sum of all the prices for each code.

[image]

In the attached picture   for example, the "Total" for code 1001 would be 190 = 100 + 90. I tried to use MATCH and INDEX functions for this but have been unsuccessful so far.

This is probably quite straight forward and I am just too confused to see it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In B2 put:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((SUMIFS($B$10:$B$14,$A$10:$A$14,$C$1:$G$1))*($C2:$G2<>""))
```

This iterates the range and checks if it is not blank and returns an array of 1,0.  then it does the sumifs on the same size range returning the price and multiplies the two arrays.  When the cell is blank it returns `0` otherwise the price.

[image]

Comment: [Whenever I see your `SUMPRODUCT()` answers...](https://media.giphy.com/media/xvlMgwlJLH1bq/giphy.gif)...I knew it would need SUMPRODUCT, but that is the one "big time" formula I still need practice on how to use, it's so versatile!

Comment: I think of SUMPRODUCT as a `For Loop`, which is not really accurate, but it works in my brain.  Then all you need to remember is that Boolean resolve to 1/0.  Then it is just math.

Comment: @BruceWayne not only are these answers uniformly excellent, they almost always result in my upvoting a question that wasn't necessarily clear to me initially, just to draw attention to the answer